# mysql query result with join/concat in php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, select

I have two tables, one for students and one for subjects,  and I want to join these two tables, so that each student list will contain all subjects belonging to them.

Can this be done in single select query alone?
Or should I query for each table and play with array results?

Table example:

[image]

Comment: can do this with [`group_concat`](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/group_concat)

Comment: JOIN is better option to go for that. Please check php manual how to do that? Or you can go with this tutorial as well:-- http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/mysqlDisplayingDataFromSeveralTables.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get the first option of the desired output:

```
SELECT   student_id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM     table1
JOIN     table2 ON table1.student_id = table2.student_no
GROUP BY student_id, name
```